How do I reuse a dynamic template in multiple emails in SendGrid?
I have a dynamic template and I have about 20 different uses of it in my app, I am able to reuse it for all uses with dynamic content except the subject never applies.
I have tried passing the subject to the Mail instance itself as well as to the dynamic data, the template picks it up and replaces for all {{{subject}}} tags except for the actual email subject.
Dynamic templates have a settings tab where you can pass a subject but I want to do this dynamically, all my emails say “No subject” and it doesn’t make sense.

It should work exactly as you described and that is also mentioned in the docs (I also just tested it and it works). Is it possible that you have a typo (or additional chars) in the mustache template?

Okay, so the docs never mention this but adding a {{subject}} tag to the template settings itself allows you to set the email subject dynamically, while also using it in the template with the {{{subject}}} tag.

